# Converting mysql_* to mysqli_* issue with mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have upgraded my app MySql_* to MySqli_* most of the things work well but i am lost in this. Its code from PayPal IPN with PHP from this website: http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

```
$txn_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$r) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
    exit(0);
}

$exists = mysql_result($r, 0);
mysql_free_result($r);
```

I have done all converting but i am lost how to write this part: this two lines are headache for me right now only this two. can any one tell how i can write this lines?

```
$exists = mysql_result($r, 0);
mysql_free_result($r);
```

Thanks all

Comment: @YourCommonSense you should identify the duplicate next time (and also actually vote to close)